Does the phrase, "God winked at" the pagan idolators' sin mean He treated them differently than the Israelites' who were idolators?
In the Old Testament, pre-Christian era, most of the "goyim" (Gentiles) were idolators.  AND, as well, one of the major sins of the O.T. Israelites was their falling into idolatry (worship of Ashteroth, Baal, etc.).
Paul addressed the Athenian philosophers on Mars Hill (academy) and said to them:

Forasmuch as then we are the offspring of God, we ought not to think that the Godhead is like unto gold, silver, or stone, graven by art and man's device.And the times of this ignorance God winked at; but now commands all men everywhere to repent... (Acts 17:29-30)

The resulting punishments levied upon the Israelites were invasions by surrounding enemies (Book of Judges), and continual worship of these idols resulted in banishment from the Promised Land. (2 Kings 24-25
But was "God's winking" at the goyim (Gentile nations) a punishment of a different order, or no drastic punishment at all---or as some state, a delayed punishment (as referenced in 1 Peter 3:19)?
["winking", hypereido, GK. "to overlook"] Is it declaring there are "degrees" of punishment for the same sins committed by different people?

Paul expands this point in the letter to the Romans:

Rom 2:14-16 - Indeed, when Gentiles, who do not have the law, do by
nature what the law requires, they are a law to themselves, even
though they do not have the law. So they show that the work of the law
is written on their hearts, their consciences also bearing witness,
and their thoughts either accusing or defending them on the day when
God will judge men’s secrets through Christ Jesus, as proclaimed by my
gospel.

This appears to be the point of Ps 87 as well - the Lord will judge people according to what each person has known, not what they have not known.  Indeed, James makes a similar point -
James 3:1 -  Not many of you should become teachers, my brothers, because you know that we who teach will be judged more strictly.
That is, greater knowledge entails greater accountability.

God was merciful to the Israelites on more than one occasion in spite of their knowledge of God.
One example:
Nehemiah 9 (ESV)

17 They refused to obey and were not mindful of the wonders that you performed among them, but they stiffened their neck and appointed a leader to return to their slavery in Egypt. But you are a God ready to forgive, gracious and merciful, slow to anger and abounding in steadfast love, and did not forsake them. 18 Even when they had made for themselves a golden calf and said, ‘This is your God who brought you up out of Egypt,’ and had committed great blasphemies, 19 you in your great mercies did not forsake them in the wilderness. The pillar of cloud to lead them in the way did not depart from them by day, nor the pillar of fire by night to light for them the way by which they should go.

God is merciful to whom he chooses and God judges as God sees fit according to God's purpose.
In Genesis 15 God is explaining to Abram that Abram's future offspring will come back to the promised land.

16 And they shall come back here in the fourth generation, for the iniquity of the Amorites is not yet complete.”

The sin of the Amorites is not yet complete. Abram's offspring will drive out the Amorites but not until God's timing is met.
God "overlooks" sin according to God's plan no matter who we are.
In Romans 3 Paul goes on to talk about who is and is not righteous.

9 What then? Are we Jews any better off? No, not at all. For we have already charged that all, both Jews and Greeks, are under sin, 10 as it is written:
“None is righteous, no, not one;
11     no one understands;
no one seeks for God.

Everyone deserves immediate judgement when they sin.
In Romans 2 we see that God's patience is meant to give us time to repent.

3 Do you suppose, O man—you who judge those who practice such things and yet do them yourself—that you will escape the judgment of God? 4 Or do you presume on the riches of his kindness and forbearance and patience, not knowing that God's kindness is meant to lead you to repentance?

